# Correcting typos in string via pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list huge list of distorted data that is stored in text that I need to do some wrangling but just cannot figure out what is the best and most efficient method. Another consideration in mind is that this data is pretty huge. Sample size 1.6 million rows and production going up to 10s of millions.

```
In [200]:data=['Bernard 51','Ber%nard Bachelor','BER78NARD$ bsc','BERnard$d B.']

In [201]:test=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Names'])

In [2020:test
Out[202]: 


  Names
0 Bernard 51
1 Ber%nard Bachelor
2 BER78NARD$ bsc
3 BERnard$d B.
```

My objective is to output

```
  Names
0 bernard
1 bernard ba
2 bernard ba
3 bernard ba
```

My pseudo code will be something like:

```
In[222]:test_processed=pd.DataFrame(test.Names.str.lower()) #covert all str to lower

In[223]:test_processed
Out[223]: 


  Names
0 bernard 51
1 ber%nard bachelor
2 ber78nard$ bsc
3 bernard$d b.

In[224]:test_processed2=pd.DataFrame(test_processed.Names.str.replace('[^\w\s]',''))
#removes punctuation/symbol typos
In[225]:test_processed2
Out[225]: 


  Names
0 bernard 51
1 bernard bachelor
2 ber78nard bsc
3 bernardd b

In[226]:BA=['bachelor','bsc','b.'] #define list to be replaced with ba

In[227]:test_processed.replace(BA,'ba') #replace list defined above with standard term
Out[227]: 

  Names
0 bernard 51
1 ber%nard bachelor
2 ber78nard$ bsc
3 bernard$d b.

#no change, didn't work
```

My observation tells me replace does not work for a list if it is applied on a Pandas DataFrame.

Reason I am not using test_processed2.Names.str.replace is because, DataFrame.str.replace does not allow using list as to be replaced.

Reason why I am using a list because I hope to easily maintain the lists as more and more different variables might come in. I would love to hear from you if you have a solution or a better alternative other than using Python or Pandas.

Comment: @sashkello 1. Main objective is to remove typos out of the data. 2.Sorry if question was not clear, but I need to effectively remove a string of data in a list and replace it.

Comment: I understand what you need. What is exactly the problem? Speed? Correctness?

Comment: @sashkello basically I cant find a way to replace a list of text with a standard term, specifically in the pd.DataFrame. The list is huge and distorted.

Comment: Looks like a reg ex problem to me? You can apply a reg-ex to the field/list I'm not up to writing it for you though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_processed.replace(BA,'ba')` will only replace *exact* matches, not parts of entries. That is, if one of your entries is 'bachelor' it will replace it just fine. For parts of the strings, you can use `regex` option as per [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html).

There is also `replace` which works on strings. So, for example, if you have a list `data` and you want to replace all instances of 'bsc' with 'ba', what you do is this:

```
data = [d.replace('bsc', 'ba') for d in data]
```

For the whole list of replacements you can do:

```
data = [d.replace(b, 'ba') for d in data for b in BA]
```

---

Now, while I feel like this is exactly what you are asking about, I should mention that this is ultimately not the right way to fix typos. Imagine you have entry "B.Bernard, msc" - you'll replace "B." with "BA" while this shouldn't have happened. Your algorithm is very basic and thus is faulty.